# Make array of struct in 2 dataframes identical ( Java Spark )

Tags: java, arrays, apache-spark, struct, apache-spark-sql

I have two data-frame (`Dataset<Row>`) with the same columns, but different order array of structs.

**df1:**

```
root
|-- root: string (nullable = false)
|-- array_nested: array (nullable = false)
|    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |    |-- array_id: integer (nullable = false)
|    |    |-- array_value: string (nullable = false)

+----+------------+
|root|array_nested|
+----+------------+
|One |[[1, 1-One]]|
+----+------------+
```

**df2:**

```
root
|-- root: string (nullable = false)
|-- array_nested: array (nullable = false)
|    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |    |-- array_value: string (nullable = false)
|    |    |-- array_id: integer (nullable = false)


+----+------------+
|root|array_nested|
+----+------------+
|Two |[[2-Two, 2]]|
+----+------------+
```

I want make the schema the same, but when I try my approach it generates and extra later of array:

```
List<Column> updatedStructNames = new ArrayList<>();
updatedStructNames.add(col("array_nested.array_id"));
updatedStructNames.add(col("array_nested.array_value"));

Column[] updatedStructNameArray = updatedStructNames.toArray(new Column[0]);
Dataset<Row> df3 = df2.withColumn("array_nested", array(struct(updatedStructNameArray)));
```

It will get generate schema like this:

```
root
 |-- root: string (nullable = false)
 |-- array_nested: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- array_id: array (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- array_value: array (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)

+----+----------------+
|root|array_nested    |
+----+----------------+
|Two |[[[2], [2-Two]]]|
+----+----------------+
```

How can I achieve the same schema?

Comment: I hope to try a little example later, but I would explode() then reassemble? https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#explode-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-

Comment: @jgp I have tried with explode too but maybe I am missing something and you have another solution in mind, I love to hear that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`transform`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#transform) function to update the struct elements of `array_nested` column:

```java
Dataset < Row > df3 = df2.withColumn(
    "array_nested",
    expr("transform(array_nested, x -> struct(x.array_id as array_id, x.array_value as array_value))")
);
```

Comment: actually that's very smart, is there any way that I can do the transform dynamically, the example in the question is simplified version of what I have, in my real use case the array of struct is much more complex, and I have the mapping like what I have in `updatedStructNameArray`

Comment: @Am1rr3zA yes, you can first get all attributes of the structs from the dataframe schema (for example `df2.selectExpr("inline(array_nested)").columns()`) then using this list you can dynamically create the struct expression to use in the transform lambda function. I'm not using Java but something like this: `Arrays.stream(listCols).map(c -> "x." + c + " as " + c).collect(Collectors.joining(","));` where `listCols` is the attributes list you get from the schema.